# Photography post processing for slideshows to music

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, slideshow, photography

I am migrating from Windows to Linux and have a question about post-processing software.

I already use GIMP / G'MIC.

**Creating a Slideshow To Music**

On Windows I use pictures2exe, a rather neat bit of software for producing slick Audio Visual Slideshows to music.

What do you advise as a Linux / Open Source alternative?

I'm not that geeky with Linux i.e I use a Ubuntu GUI desktop interface and don't do any command line scripts etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/) as a video editing program and also use it for timelapses. I think it will probably suit you quite well. It is open source and not that hard to use. You may find [the official manual](https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/Introduction) helpful.

To create a slideshow all you have to do is

- Import a folder or pictures where all your photos are in as a slideshow clip (click on the arrow next to the **import clip** button and select **slideshow clip**)
- Choose how long the pictures should be shown for and other settings. It automatically cuts them to a clip.
- Put the music in one channel add the clip in another and you're done!

Comment: thanks , i downloaded kdenlive yesterday , i didn't realise you could do slideshows too. I assume you can have different transitions per slide and add text to slides too ?

Comment: Well not the way I described. You could also import the pictures one by one (just drag and drop) and add transitions (and titles) individually. I guess it is quite a bit more work but the final show is definitly more interesting.

Comment: I will give your recommendations a try this weekend. I was always aware that pictures2exe created 'executable' files on windows, which was not the ideal way to share our slideshows with your friends and family. Kdenlive looks really good , I will compare the features with pictures2exe and reply with my findings, btw pictures2exe is not open source or free, it is a paid for solution.